# Javascript Unordered List from Array

Tags: javascript

I just came across this on the w3schools Javascript tutorial:

```
var fruits, text, fLen, i;
fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;

text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
```

I understand what arrays are and how to loop through them, but I need help with the part where they are creating the unordered list from the array. Can anyone help with this please?

Thanks in advance,
Wasi

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Answer (score 1):

That code **doesn't** create an unordered list from an array. It creates a string containing HTML markup for one, by starting out with a string:

```
text = "<ul>";
```

then adding to it once for each entry in the string:

```
text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
//   ^^-- adds to the end of the string (well, technically it creates a new string
//        and updates `text` to contain the new string)
```

then adding the ending `</ul>` after the loop:

```
text += "</ul>";
```

At the end, `text` is a string with this HTML in it:

```
<ul><li>Banana</li><li>Orange</li><li>Apple</li><li>Mango</li></ul>
```

To actually create an unordered list, something has to *parse* that HTML. They probably do something like this later:

```
someElement.innerHTML = text;
```

Live Example:

```js
var fruits, text, fLen, i;
fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;

text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.getElementById("some-element").innerHTML = text;
```

```html
<div id="some-element"></div>
```

Assigning to the [`innerHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property on an element makes the browser parse the HTML and creates the appropriate DOM nodes/elements, then replace the element's contents with those nodes/elements.

There are other ways, though, such as [`insertAdjacentHTML`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML) which lets you insert nodes/elements before an element, after it, inside it at the beginning (without replacing its existing content), or inside it at the end (without replacing its existing content). For example, this inserts at the end of `body`:

```js
var fruits, text, fLen, i;
fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;

text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

document.body.insertAdjacentHTML(
  "beforeend", text
);
```

```html
<div>Content already in the `body` element before `insertAdjacentHTML`.</div>
```

Or you can use [`DOMParser`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DOMParser) if you want to parse it without adding it to any document:

```js
var fruits, text, fLen, i;
fruits = ["Banana", "Orange", "Apple", "Mango"];
fLen = fruits.length;

text = "<ul>";
for (i = 0; i < fLen; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + fruits[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";

var parser = new DOMParser();
var doc = parser.parseFromString(text, "text/html");
var liElements = doc.querySelectorAll("li");
console.log("`li` elements found: " + liElements.length);
```

Comment: Hey Crowder, thanks so much. I am sorry I actually didn't copy enough to include the html part: document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = text; their example does have it. Also, I almost began to understand it just after I posted the question and your explanation helped enough to grasp it fully, now I understand it fully. Thanks again

Comment: @WasiUllah - No worries! Looks like I guessed right at the next thing they were going to do. :-) I have to caution you about w3schools: It has very wide coverage of topics, but often incomplete or even incorrect coverage. I would recommend instead using [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/) and well-reviewed JavaScript, HTML, and CSS tutorials or books instead.

Comment: I agree with you, I'm finding some of their tutorials very difficult to understand as there are little to no explanations, like the one in question. Can you point me in the direction of any HTML, CSS and Javascript books that are available online, ideally as a free download? Thanks in advance

Comment: @WasiUllah - MDN really is very good, and collaboratively-edited, with good coverage of HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. For JavaScript itself, there's [Axel Rauschmayer's *JavaScript for Impatient Programmers*](https://exploringjs.com/impatient-js/index.html). I haven't read it, but Axel is very knowledgeable. He is a bit academic, which some may find offputting. The book is brand-new. Later this year my book [*JavaScript: The New Toys*](https://www.amazon.com/gp/product/1119367956) will be coming out, but it's about the new features in ES2015-ES2019, it's not a "from scratch" book. Happy coding!

Comment: Thanks so much Crowder. I will try to download that book. Wish you all the best of luck with your new book! Thanks again